# In Win7, How to set a shortcut key with the windows logo key?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Windows logo key provides some system shortcut keys like <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for "Run" and so on, which I find to be very convenient.
But when I wish to set some my own shortcut keys in a shortcut's "Properties", I find I am not able to use the "<kbd>win</kbd>" key but only <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>.

Is there any way to utilize the <kbd>win</kbd> key to DIY a shortcut key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**WinHotKey**](http://directedge.us/content/winhotkey) to make your own Windows key shortcuts.